# Pyspark Dataframe Phone Number Format

Tags: function, for-loop, pyspark, format, phone-number

I have a table, approx. 1K rows and two columns. The first row is the emp_id and the second is tel_num. The tel_num column is not formatted all the same...some examples are (555) 555-9876, +18763334455, 505-999-888x222, some have no values...and so on. The goal is to format them all the same 10 digits without the leading 1s or any extensions.

The table looks like the following

| emp_id | tel_num |
| --- | --- |
| Jon Doe | +18763334455 |
| Cal Foe | 505-999-8888x222 |
| Ho Moe | nan |
| GI joe | 676.909.4321 |

trying to make this...

| Column A | tel_format |
| --- | --- |
| Jon Doe | (876) 333-4455 |
| Cal Foe | (505) 999-8888 |
| Ho Moe | nan |
| GI Joe | (679) 909-4321 |

I tried this format...
I'm using databricks.
The current process i tried is somewhat like this...

```
def formatphone(ph_var):
    ...some process
    return formatted_ph

df = df.withColumn('tel_format', formatphone(df.tel_num))
```

I can't get it to work.

Comment: Can you please fix the formatting of your post? You can see [/editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help on how to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following function, assuming that all possible formats are shown in your sample data.
To use this function in `withColumn()`, you need to create a UDF from it.

```
@F.udf(returnType=F.StringType())
def format_telephone_number(phone_number):
    if phone_number is None:
        return None
    if phone_number=='nan':
        return None
    if phone_number[0]== '+':
        return '('  + phone_number[2:5] + ') ' + phone_number[5:8] + '-' + phone_number[8:12]
    if '-' in phone_number:
        return '('  + phone_number[0:3] + ') ' + phone_number[4:7] + '-' + phone_number[8:12]
    if '.' in phone_number:
        return '('  + phone_number[0:3] + ') ' + phone_number[4:7] + '-' + phone_number[8:12]
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: It runs, but when I want to display the results. I get this error...
An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: @ChrisBeredimas Can you retry? I updated  the code above. What is the data type of the column? I assume it is of stringType? nan is typically used in integer, float, ... columns. Is the nan value here just a string 'nan', or is it actually None? If it is a string, then it should be solved with the fix above. Also make sure that you there are no different formats possible. I recreated the example you gave, and it worked with the changes.

Comment: Thanks. It works. Now I can take what you provided and add to it.